# how to get the profile information of any user when ones he has signed in or login through FireBase AuthUI

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have deployed FirebaseAuthUI in my android app. Where user can login in my app through Facebook, Twitter, Phone number, or Gmail. but the problem I am facing is that I don't know that how can I retrieve the information of the user(name of the user if he has logged in through Facebook, Twitter, Gmail and  phone number of the user if he has signed in or logged in through phone number) when once he has logged or signed in my app through FireBaseAuthUI. Can I somehow retrieve this information in onActivityResult Method? If not then how can I retrieve the information (name,email-id and phone number of user if he has logged in signed through phone number verification ) of my user every time when he login or signs in my app

here is my code

```
package com.example.anonymous.userlogin;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.ErrorCodes;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.IdpResponse;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 123;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null)
           {

           }
        else
            {
            // not signed in
                startActivityForResult(
                        AuthUI.getInstance()
                                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                                .setAvailableProviders(
                                        Arrays.asList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),
                                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.PHONE_VERIFICATION_PROVIDER).build(),
                                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build(),
                                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER).build(),
                                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.TWITTER_PROVIDER).build()))
                                .setTheme(R.style.MyLoginTheme)
                                .build(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // RC_SIGN_IN is the request code you passed into startActivityForResult(...) when starting the sign in flow.
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);


            // Successfully signed in
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                finish();
                return;
            } else {
                // Sign in failed
                if (response == null) {
                    // User pressed back button

                    return;
                }

                if (response.getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.NO_NETWORK) {

                    return;
                }

                if (response.getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.UNKNOWN_ERROR) {

                    return;
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after succesful login you can try the following code snippet

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
```

and try to get some relevant data from the user object. Hope it helps.